# What does multiset imply?

Tags: combinatorics, multisets

Does a multiset operation (($^n_k$)) only work for sets with identical elements, or does it also apply to replacement of distinct elements. Is there any difference in the calculation?
Furthermore, is there any distinction between "choosing from a set" and the opposite action of "filling an order", where elements from an endless supply must be chosen to fit a set or sets with restrictions (quotes are for lack of a better phrase)? Are there different names for these two sides of the same concept? For reference, I think of the set chosen from as the "source", and the chosen set as the "selection". When we restrict the selection, it seems to use the same operations, but maybe not always. Can someone shed a little light on these ideas?

Comment: The number $\left(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\right)$ or also written $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ (*unless your notation reverses the positions of $n$ and $k$, both are in use frustratingly*) is the number of non-negative integer solutions to the system $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k=n$.  It can be thought of as the number of multisets of size $n$ where each element is taken from the set $\{1,2,3,\dots,k\}$ (*repetition allowed, order not mattering*).  It is common to make the analogy of balls and bins for many of these introductory counting notations.  Here, $n$ identical balls put in $k$ distinct bins.

Comment: Now... does it matter whether in our mind we are treating the balls as the subject of the sentence?  Where we take each ball and choose what bin each goes in to?  Versus having treated the bins as the subject... take each bin and choose some of the remaining balls to be placed in it?  Not really for counting purposes or organizing our thoughts, no.  It can matter when moving to probability questions related to this, as one will more closely resemble the random processes involved.

Comment: I take it from this that it applies to replacement as well (repetitions of the distinct numbers, above).

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to start with the more familiar stars and bars formula, $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ for putting $n$ **identical** objects into $k$ **distinct** bins

An example could be distributing $7$ identical ice cream bars to $5$ people, so (permitting $0$ assignments), the answer is $\dbinom{11}4$

But what if we want to buy a total of $7$ ice cream bars from a parlor having $5$ distinct varieties ?
In other words, we can **multichoose**, buy any number of each variety subject to a total of $5$

This can be represented as $\left(\!\dbinom{k}{n}\!\right)$ to again give an answer of $\dbinom{11}{4}$

Notice that we have deliberately interchanged the meaning of $n$ and $k$ so as to get identical answers to both, *which directly implies* that putting $n$ identical items **into** $k$ distinct bins is the same as **taking out** a total of $n$ items from $k$ distinct types of objects.